# WPF, не могу адекватно подключить картинки на фон

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь добавить картинки на фон кнопок, когда пытаюсь собрать проект пишет о том, что картинки по пути не найдены, но на самой форме картинки отображаются, насколько я понимаю я просто не там храню media файлы. Подскажите как решить проблему.

**Пример кнопки**

```
<Button Width="30" Height="30" 
                    Margin="0,0,100,0" BorderThickness="0">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="media/inst.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

**Скриншот того, что всё отображается верно**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка афектается в initializeComponent();

**Скриншот ошибки**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**текст ошибки**

```
IOException: Не удается найти ресурс "media/inst.png".
```

**Рабочий каталог**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы добавили эту картинку в проект и какой тип сборки она имеет у вас в проекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте изображения в ресурсы (правой кнопкой на папке Resources в обозревателе решений) как существующий элемент, а затем в xaml сделайте ресурс:

```
<Image x:Key="NameOfResource" Width="25" Height="25" Source="вашеИзображение.png"/>
```